# Simple distance query is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have latitude and longitude defined as decimal(9, 6) in my zip code table, per the zip code database company's instructions.

I take a lat/lon feed it to a function in my c# program and it gives me lat/lon in boundaries for getting a list of lat/lon from the database (radius distance)

The sql code does not work with the longitude.

**SELECT TOP(10) * FROM USZipCode WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN 34.7600283409472 AND 37.6513716590528) 
AND (Longitude BETWEEN -76.383333 AND -76.818238)**

But if I skip the longitude then it works, or at least returns records even if they are the wrong ones.

**SELECT TOP(10) * FROM USZipCode WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN 34.7600283409472 AND 37.6513716590528)**

The only thing I can think of; is that since the longitude is negative that the sql ain't working?

This is SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and I've also tried the Lat > x and Lat > y etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

SELECT TOP(10) * FROM USZipCode WHERE (Latitude BETWEEN 34.7600283409472 AND 37.6513716590528) AND (Longitude BETWEEN -76.818238 AND  -76.383333)

It IS because of negative numbers.  -76.3 is a larger number than -76.8, so you need to reverse them.

Answer (score 2):

Flip your upper and lower negative limits:

`-76.818238 is **less than** -76.383333`

Answer (score 2):

-76.818238 is less than -76.383333.

Try:

```
 AND (Longitude BETWEEN -76.818238 AND -76.383333)
```

Answer (score 2):

The lower value needs to be first in the BETWEEN expression...  Not the lower absolute value.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY
)


DECLARE @i int
SET @i = -10
WHILE @i < 11
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID) SELECT @i
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @MyTable
WHERE ID between 3 AND 6

  -- no records because there is no value which is greater than -3 and less than -6
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
WHERE ID between -3 AND -6

SELECT * FROM @MyTable
WHERE ID between -6 AND -3

SELECT * FROM @MyTable
WHERE ID between -3 AND 3
```

---

Fun fact, Sql Server's query optimizer detects the bad range in that second query and does not even perform IO on @MyTable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute with a radius it's more complicated, use this function

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getDistance]
(
@lat1 float,
@lon1 float,
@lat2 float,
@lon2 float
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result float

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SET @result = (SQRT((69.1*(@lat2-@lat1)) * (69.1*(@lat2-@lat1)) + (53.0*(@lon2 - @lon1))*(53.0*(@lon2 - @lon1)))/0.621369949495) 

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result

END
```

And like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE dbo.getDistance(latitue,longitude,@lat,@long) <= @radius
```

Comment: Off topic. Cool, but definitely **not** what the OP asked.

Comment: "I take a lat/lon feed it to a function in my c# program and it gives me lat/lon in boundaries for getting a list of lat/lon from the database (radius distance)", what he is doing is non sense (take lat/lon between 2 values).

Comment: sure - he winds up with all points in a square region. 2 points - 1. His query criteria is sargable. 2. He can further filter that result by calculated distance in his c# app.

Comment: @David, if he want to use an index, he can do a subquery to do a first filter and then a second query to filter on the distance. I tried my query on a table with 300 000 row (on a dev machine), and the results shows up in less than a sec. I'm allergic to data-filtering in c#. And I'm not off-topic.

Comment: Yeah, I pass it to a program that gives me the lat/lon bounds in miles or km of a given distance to a lat/lon. e.g. it returns 2 lat, 2 lon.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query and see if you have any records in this range -

```
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM USZipCode 
WHERE (Longitude BETWEEN -76.818238 AND -76.383333)
```

My guess is that you do not have any data in the longitude range specified
and also -76.818238 is less than -76.383333

Comment: I have data, like the first answer said, the numbers needed to be reversed, then the query worked.

Comment: @Rick - yes, thought so. Have mentioned that in my answer too ;)